# SKAction not working while [SKScene enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skaction, skscene

I'm going to add some `SKAction` animation before delete nodes from my `SKScene`. When I'm trying to do it, SKAction executed just at first 2-4 sprites from 10-40. If I commented `[node runAction:action];` and just put `[node removeFromParent];` all works fine. Can somebody help me, what I'm doing wrong here:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"dblock" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
            TRBlock *droppedBlock = (TRBlock *)node;
            if ([linesToRemove containsIndex:droppedBlock.localCoordinates.y]) {
                //[node runAction:animationAction completion:^{
                    [node removeFromParent];
                //}];
            } else {
                if ([linesToRemove indexLessThanIndex:droppedBlock.localCoordinates.y] != NSNotFound) {
                    droppedBlock.localCoordinates = TRBoardCoordinatesMake(droppedBlock.localCoordinates.x,
                                                                           droppedBlock.localCoordinates.y - completeLines.count);
                    CGPoint targetPoint = calculatedPositionFromBlockBoardCoordinates(droppedBlock.localCoordinates);
                    droppedBlock.position = targetPoint;
                }
                //                [droppedBlock runAction:[SKAction moveToY:targetPoint.y duration:0.2]];
            }
        }];
```

as you can see all `SKAction`s commented here and all works fine, but how I can do that with animation?
I already tried a lot of different `SKAction`s and even `sequence` and `group`, `runWithCompletion:` - same result, works for a few first `SKNode`s, but trying to run on dozens.

Comment: can animationAction ever be nil, or somehow not make it to completion?

Comment: No, I checked it's not nil. It even not works when I use [node runAction:[SKAction removeFromSuperview]];